# UnicodeDecodeError when reading from CSV/List: Unexpected End of Data

Tags: python, list, csv, unicode, decode

so I am trying to use something called DeepMoji to grade a csv full of tweets. The tweets must be encoded in Unicode. I have been able to make it work with a small dataset, but with the one that i have of over 200,000 points, i am receiving this error: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 254: unexpected end of data.

The code and solution I have tried are the following, but gives the same error, does anyone have any ideas?

```
TEST_SENTENCES = []
with open('Cleaned_Data3.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        TEST_SENTENCES.append(row["Tweet"])
    try:
        [x.encode('utf-8') for x in TEST_SENTENCES]
    except:
        for rows in TEST_SENTENCES: #attempt to fix the problem 
            str=unicode(str, errors='replace')
```

Here is the full error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pjame\Desktop\DeepMoji-master\examples\score_texts_emojis.py", line 24, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py2.py", line 217, in next
    row = csv.DictReader.next(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 108, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py2.py", line 128, in next
    for value in row]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 254: unexpected end of data
```

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to Python 3? The `csv` module natively supports Unicode strings there. You'll be able to concentrate more on actual work.

Comment: @lenz: did you read the error message? It comes from the utf8 codec, meaning that this codes already tries to process utf8 input and find something different.

Comment: What is your Python version? And what lines triggers the error?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: yes, I figured it might be caused by `csv` making wrong segmentations (because it is unaware of the text's encoding).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to Python 3, the module I am using assumes that I am using Python 2. I am using 2.7. The error must be in the data itself, as I can run smaller csv files through fine. This is just a large dataset. I just ran it through again and it works.
It seems like the error results from the actual decoding of the csv. I have added the fll error above.

Comment: If I could just see the csv file itself in utf-8, I could search for the null or end bytes and just delete them, but I need to be able to search for them.

Comment: For reference, here is the file im using: https://github.com/bfelbo/DeepMoji/blob/master/examples/encode_texts.py